# Prevent two event's from firing right after each other

Tags: javascript

I have written a nonsensical program to demonstrate my problem.

**What should happen**

Pressing enter when the input field contains the word "text" displays the message *"Don't change me until I'm ready"*

waits for enter to be pressed again then clears the input field and display the message *"Ha I changed you before you were ready"*

**What is happening**

Pressing enter when the input field contains the word "text" triggers both events one right after other other.

** what I have tried**

- event.stopPropagation();
- using a Boolean variable to add and remove the container event as needed.

however, neither have fixed the problem.

```js
const inputField = document.querySelector('.inputField');
const inform = document.querySelector('.inform');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

inputField.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
  /*event.stopPropagation();*/
    matchInput();
  }
});

function matchInput() {
  if (inputField.value === "text")
    inform.innerHTML = "Don't change me until i'm ready";

  window.addEventListener("keydown", nextInput);
};

function nextInput() {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    inputField.value = "";
    inform.innerHTML = "Ha I changed you before you were ready!";
    container.removeEventListener("keydown", nextInput);
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" name="" value="text" autofocus class="inputField">
  <div class="inform">
 </div>
```

Comment: Check the elements you are adding the event handlers on. Either add (and remove) them all on the `inputField` or the `container`. But not the first on the input, the second on `window` (which you then try to remove from the `container`)

Comment: Adding both to the same element works as expected. Thank you. Can you explain why having the same event on different elements causes this problem. while your suggestion solves this problem. I'm curious to know because i'm sure i might end up in the same position in which different element have the same event,

Comment: You're adding the second event handler on the top most element `window`. After the first event handler finished its work (adding the second one), the event bubbles up the DOM until it reaches `window` where now your second event handler waits...

Comment: Since the problem in event bubbling why don't event.stopPropagation(); fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you're making your life difficult... (tio, te estás complicando la vida...).
Why don't you try with just one event handler:

```
inputField.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
     if (inputField.value === "text") inform.innerHTML = "Don't change me until i'm ready";
     else {
        inputField.value = "";
        inform.innerHTML = "Ha I changed you before you were ready!";
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: If that is what i needed, I would done it that way. i can't do it that way :( because the messages was just there to better explain myself. What is important is the fact some functions are calling other functions and within one of the called functions there is an event listener that is conflicting with  one above.

Comment: The code provided was simple to mimic a much more complex problem. rather than type it all I chose to write something much simpler that demonstrates the problem. I'm sorry i didn't explain it better.